# Recommended procedure for Javascript variable reuse

Tags: javascript, variables, naming-conventions, variable-declaration

I am trying to cut down on the number of declared variables in a project, because - if for no other reason - it makes me a little crazy.

I have two possibilities for the following pseudocode. One possibility is (inside a loop):

```
jsObject=longfunctionWithManyParameters(that,returns,something);
jsObject=anotherFunctionThatReturns(jsObject, modified);
jsObject=etc;
// loop close
return jsObject
```

The other option is to create a new variable name for each step of the process, e.g. `jsObjectA`, `jsObjectB`.

And while doing this, I realised that this isn't the first time I've had this question.  They both seem "wrong" to me, and I think probably there is a better way to write the code to not get into this situation.  That being said:  Apart from my hyper-useless over-perfection, is there any reason to avoid or to embrace one or the other way of doing this here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about program architecture should be asked on [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: This is too opinionated for SO, but might be a good fit on that other site. But I'll bet they'll tell you to get over your aversion to variables. They should have meaningful names that describe the abstraction they represent.

Comment: @Barmar agreed ; voted off-topic for same reasons. Sorry

Comment: @Barmar - I don't need a lot - that get's as close to an answer as I need.